# Which data structure(or type) would be useful for defining the digit amount of a number?

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, numbers, digit

Hi there fellow programmers,

I know that should be easy but I need to define the digit amount of a number for trying all the combinations in a project. The digit number shouldn't be affected by users actions because the change of the digit amount causes "Index out of range" error. (Yes, I am using arrays for this)

Let's say, I have to use four digit number.

```
int Nmr=1000;
Nmr--;
Console.Write(Nmr);// The output will be 999 but I need 0999
```

Using string type and if statements could lead to an alternative solution...

```
int Nmr=1000;
Nmr--;
string number=Nmr.ToString();
if (Nmr<1000) number="0"+number;
if (Nmr<100) number="00"+number;
if (Nmr<10) number="000"+number;
Console.Write(Nmr); //That gives me 0999
```

But then, it gives me complexity and unneccessary time loss which I wouldn't want to encounter. I am not even talking about the greater values.

So, what would you suggest?
Edit: Both ToString("0000") and PadLeft methods are useful.

Thank you Mateus Coutinho Martino and Blorgbeard. =)

Comment: You can specify a format when calling ToString: `Nmr.ToString("0000");`

Comment: If you always need the leading '0's, simply do `Nmr.PadLeft('0',4)`. This will ensure you always have at least 4 characters, and if not, it will add the char you want to be that specified length

Comment: Also, your alternative solution will add too many zeros for numbers less than 100. You need some `else` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, do with ***PadLeft*** method of String class ...

```
int Nmr=1000;    
Nmr--;    
Console.Write(Nmr.ToString().PadLeft(4,'0')); //That gives you ever four digits.
```

Or if you prefer better explained ...

```
int Nmr=1000;    
Nmr--;    
String number = Nmr.ToString();
Console.Write(number.PadLeft(4,'0')); // four digits again;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can specify a format when calling ToString - e.g.

```
string number = Nmr.ToString("0000");
```

See the docs: [`Int32.ToString(string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wch342y.aspx) and [Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The "0" custom format specifier serves as a zero-placeholder symbol.
Here's a little idea for you:

```
            double numberS;

            numberS = 123;
             Console.WriteLine(numberS.ToString("00000"));
             Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:00000}", value));
             // Displays 00123
```

You can look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx for more.